# 'negative' Duration in Joda, a bug or a feature?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

When trying to compare two DateTime I wrote this code

```
private boolean compareTime(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2) 
{ 
    long d1 = (new Duration(dt1.getMillis() - dt2.getMillis())).getMillis();
    long d2 = Duration.standardHours(1).getMillis(); 
    return  d1  < d2; 
}
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
Thread.sleep(250);
DateTime dt2 = dt1.plusHours(2);
System.out.println(compareTime(dt1,dt2));
System.out.println(compareTime(dt2,dt1));
```

Expected this to print

```
false
false
```

But it was

```
true
false
```

So when I looked into  Duration CTOR, then turned out it actually created a Duration with negative millisecond duration (getMils() returns -ve).

What is the meaning of -ve Duration ? 
(To keep it very objective)
Is this a bug or a feature ?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds entirely sensible to me. You're passing a negative number of milliseconds into the constructor - why would you *expect* that to become positive?

A negative duration is simply a negative amount of time - the time from "now" to "some time in the past", for example. It allows sensible arithmetic:

```
Instant x = ...;
Instant y = ...;
// Duration from x to y, although the result isn't "anchored" (it forgets x and y)
Duration d = new Duration(x, y);
Instant y2 = x.plus(d); // y2 is now equal to y
```

Without negative durations, this would be impossible.

If you always want a non-negative duration, just call `Math.abs` - or in your case, don't use `Duration` at all for `d1`:

```
long d1 = Math.Abs(dt1.getMillis() - dt2.getMillis());
```

Comment: According to documentation, it is 'Interval' that has start Instant and end Instant.  
For 'Duration'  there is no  start instant.

You can go back in the time, but the time is still positive I suppose.

Comment: @Ajeet: Yes, an `Interval` knows the two instants involved - but the duration is the *amount* of time from ("now" to "some time in the past"). In other words, the duration from interval.start to interval.end is such that adding it to interval.start gives you interval.end.