# Negative FiniteDuration in scala?

Tags: scala

Why is it possible/allowed to have negative duration in scala?

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> 1.minutes
res0: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 1 minute

scala> -10.minutes
res1: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = -10 minutes
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably to allow operations between two durations. I believe it would be better to ask this question on the contributors discourse or gitter channel.

Comment: FWIW, `java.time.Duration` can also be negative. And John Skeet talks about this for JodaTime over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629281/negative-duration-in-joda-a-bug-or-a-feature